# django-imagekit throwing AttributeError exception in ImageCacheFile default ctor function

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-imagekit, django-photologue

I am working on a project, using the following components:

> django: v2.2.10
>
> django-podcasting: 1.3.2
>
> django-imagekit: 4.0.2
>
> django-photologue: 3.11

When I try to add a new podcast show, I get the following error message:

> AttributeError at /admin/podcasting/show/add/

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /admin/podcasting/show/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imagekit/cachefiles/__init__.py", line 37, in __init__
    name = generator.cachefile_name
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imagekit/specs/__init__.py", line 95, in cachefile_name
    return fn(self)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imagekit/cachefiles/namers.py", line 40, in source_name_as_path
    '%s%s' % (generator.get_hash(), ext)))
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imagekit/specs/__init__.py", line 134, in get_hash
    self.source.name,
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/photologue/models.py", line 345, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 606, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1645, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1529, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1572, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1088, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 790, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imagekit/specs/sourcegroups.py", line 33, in receiver
    fn(self, sender=sender, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imagekit/specs/sourcegroups.py", line 102, in post_save_receiver
    attname)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imagekit/specs/sourcegroups.py", line 124, in dispatch_signal
    signal.send(sender=source_group, source=file)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imagekit/registry.py", line 115, in source_group_receiver
    file = ImageCacheFile(spec)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imagekit/cachefiles/__init__.py", line 40, in __init__
    name = fn(generator)
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imagekit/cachefiles/namers.py", line 91, in hash
    '%s%s' % (generator.get_hash(), ext)))
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imagekit/specs/__init__.py", line 134, in get_hash
    self.source.name,
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/photologue/models.py", line 345, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError
[16/Mar/2020 22:47:47] "POST /admin/podcasting/show/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 221587
```

#### imagekit/cachefiles/**init**.py

```
class ImageCacheFile(BaseIKFile, ImageFile):
    """
    A file that represents the result of a generator. Creating an instance of
    this class is not enough to trigger the generation of the file. In fact,
    one of the main points of this class is to allow the creation of the file
    to be deferred until the time that the cache file strategy requires it.

    """
    def __init__(self, generator, name=None, storage=None, cachefile_backend=None, cachefile_strategy=None):
        """
        :param generator: The object responsible for generating a new image.
        :param name: The filename
        :param storage: A Django storage object that will be used to save the
            file.
        :param cachefile_backend: The object responsible for managing the
            state of the file.
        :param cachefile_strategy: The object responsible for handling events
            for this file.

        """
        self.generator = generator

        if not name:
            try:
                name = generator.cachefile_name
            except AttributeError:
                fn = get_by_qname(settings.IMAGEKIT_CACHEFILE_NAMER, 'namer')
                name = fn(generator)
        self.name = name

        storage = storage or getattr(generator, 'cachefile_storage',
            None) or get_singleton(settings.IMAGEKIT_DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE,
            'file storage backend')
        self.cachefile_backend = (
            cachefile_backend
            or getattr(generator, 'cachefile_backend', None)
            or get_singleton(settings.IMAGEKIT_DEFAULT_CACHEFILE_BACKEND,
                             'cache file backend'))
        self.cachefile_strategy = (
            cachefile_strategy
            or getattr(generator, 'cachefile_strategy', None)
            or get_singleton(settings.IMAGEKIT_DEFAULT_CACHEFILE_STRATEGY,
                             'cache file strategy')
        )

        super(ImageCacheFile, self).__init__(storage=storage)
```

#### photologue/models.py

```
class ImageModel(models.Model):
     # ...
    
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        global size_method_map
        if not size_method_map:
            init_size_method_map()
        di = size_method_map.get(name, None)
        if di is not None:
            result = partial(getattr(self, di['base_name']), di['size'])
            setattr(self, name, result)
            return result
        else:
            raise AttributeError
```

#### /path/to/django-podcasting/podcasting/models.py

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Show(models.Model):
    """
    A podcast show, which has many episodes.
    """
    EXPLICIT_CHOICES = (
        (1, _("yes")),
        (2, _("no")),
        (3, _("clean")),
    )
    uuid = UUIDField(_("id"), unique=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(_("created"), auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_("updated"), auto_now=True, editable=False)
    published = models.DateTimeField(_("published"), null=True, blank=True, editable=False)

    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site, verbose_name=_('Sites'))

    ttl = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        _("ttl"), default=1440,
        help_text=_("""``Time to Live,`` the number of minutes a channel can be
        cached before refreshing."""))

    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="podcast_shows",
        verbose_name=_("owner"),
        help_text=_("""Make certain the user account has a name and e-mail address."""))

    editor_email = models.EmailField(
        _("editor email"), blank=True,
        help_text=_("Email address of the person responsible for the feed's content."))
    webmaster_email = models.EmailField(
        _("webmaster email"), blank=True,
        help_text=_("Email address of the person responsible for channel publishing."))

    if 'licenses' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        license = models.ForeignKey(License, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("license"))
    else:
        license = models.CharField(
            _("license"), max_length=255,
            help_text=_("To publish a podcast to iTunes it is required to set a license type."))

    organization = models.CharField(
        _("organization"), max_length=255,
        help_text=_("Name of the organization, company or Web site producing the podcast."))
    link = models.URLField(_("link"), help_text=_("""URL of either the main website or the
        podcast section of the main website."""))

    enable_comments = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    author_text = models.CharField(
        _("author text"), max_length=255, help_text=_("""
            This tag contains the name of the person or company that is most
            widely attributed to publishing the Podcast and will be
            displayed immediately underneath the title of the Podcast.
            The suggested format is: 'email@example.com (Full Name)'
            but 'Full Name' only, is acceptable. Multiple authors
            should be comma separated."""))

    title = models.CharField(_("title"), max_length=255)
    slug = AutoSlugField(_("slug"), populate_from="title", unique="True")

    subtitle = models.CharField(
        _("subtitle"), max_length=255,
        help_text=_("Looks best if only a few words, like a tagline."))

    # If the show is not on iTunes, many fields may be ignored in your user forms
    on_itunes = models.BooleanField(
        _("iTunes"), default=True,
        help_text=_("Checked if the podcast is submitted to iTunes"))

    description_pretty = models.TextField(
        _("pretty description"), blank=True,
        help_text="May be longer than 4000 characters and contain HTML tags and styling.")

    description = models.TextField(
        _("description"), max_length=4000, help_text=_("""
            This is your chance to tell potential subscribers all about your
            podcast. Describe your subject matter, media format,
            episode schedule, and other relevant info so that they
            know what they'll be getting when they subscribe. In
            addition, make a list of the most relevant search terms
            that you want yourp podcast to match, then build them into
            your description. Note that iTunes removes podcasts that
            include lists of irrelevant words in the itunes:summary,
            description, or itunes:keywords tags. This field can be up
            to 4000 characters."""))

    if 'photologue' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        original_image = models.ForeignKey(Photo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("image"), default=None, null=True, blank=True, help_text=_("""
                A podcast must have 1400 x 1400 pixel cover art in JPG or PNG
                format using RGB color space. See our technical spec for
                details. To be eligible for featuring on iTunes Stores,
                choose an attractive, original, and square JPEG (.jpg) or
                PNG (.png) image at a size of 1400x1400 pixels. The image
                will be scaled down to 50x50 pixels at smallest in iTunes.
                For reference see the <a
                href="http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html#metadata">iTunes
                Podcast specs</a>.<br /><br /> For episode artwork to
                display in iTunes, image must be <a
                href="http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080501164348AAjvBvQ">
                saved to file's <strong>metadata</strong></a> before
                enclosure uploading!"""))
    else:
        original_image = ImageField(
            _("image"), upload_to=get_show_upload_folder, blank=True, help_text=_("""
                A podcast must have 1400 x 1400 pixel cover art in JPG or PNG
                format using RGB color space. See our technical spec for
                details. To be eligible for featuring on iTunes Stores,
                choose an attractive, original, and square JPEG (.jpg) or
                PNG (.png) image at a size of 1400x1400 pixels. The image
                will be scaled down to 50x50 pixels at smallest in iTunes.
                For reference see the <a
                href="http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html#metadata">iTunes
                Podcast specs</a>.<br /><br /> For episode artwork to
                display in iTunes, image must be <a
                href="http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080501164348AAjvBvQ">
                saved to file's <strong>metadata</strong></a> before
                enclosure uploading!"""))

    if ResizeToFill:
        admin_thumb_sm = ImageSpecField(source="original_image",
                                        processors=[ResizeToFill(50, 50)],
                                        options={"quality": 100})
        admin_thumb_lg = ImageSpecField(source="original_image",
                                        processors=[ResizeToFill(450, 450)],
                                        options={"quality": 100})
        img_show_sm = ImageSpecField(source="original_image",
                                     processors=[ResizeToFill(120, 120)],
                                     options={"quality": 100})
        img_show_lg = ImageSpecField(source="original_image",
                                     processors=[ResizeToFill(550, 550)],
                                     options={"quality": 100})
        img_itunes_sm = ImageSpecField(source="original_image",
                                       processors=[ResizeToFill(144, 144)],
                                       options={"quality": 100})
        img_itunes_lg = ImageSpecField(source="original_image",
                                       processors=[ResizeToFill(1400, 1400)],
                                       options={"quality": 100})

    feedburner = models.URLField(
        _("feedburner url"), blank=True,
        help_text=_("""Fill this out after saving this show and at least one
            episode. URL should look like "http://feeds.feedburner.com/TitleOfShow".
            See <a href="http://code.google.com/p/django-podcast/">documentation</a>
            for more. <a href="http://www.feedburner.com/fb/a/ping">Manually ping</a>"""))

    # iTunes specific fields
    explicit = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        _("explicit"), default=1, choices=EXPLICIT_CHOICES,
        help_text=_("``Clean`` will put the clean iTunes graphic by it."))
    redirect = models.URLField(
        _("redirect"), blank=True,
        help_text=_("""The show's new URL feed if changing
            the URL of the current show feed. Must continue old feed for at least
            two weeks and write a 301 redirect for old feed."""))
    keywords = models.CharField(
        _("keywords"), max_length=255, blank=True,
        help_text=_("""A comma-demlimitedlist of up to 12 words for iTunes
            searches. Perhaps include misspellings of the title."""))
    itunes = models.URLField(
        _("itunes store url"), blank=True,
        help_text=_("""Fill this out after saving this show and at least one
            episode. URL should look like:
            "http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=000000000".
            See <a href="http://code.google.com/p/django-podcast/">documentation</a> for more."""))

    twitter_tweet_prefix = models.CharField(
        _("Twitter tweet prefix"), max_length=80,
        help_text=_("Enter a short ``tweet_text`` prefix for new episodes on this show."),
        blank=True)

    objects = ShowQuerySet.as_manager()
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Show")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Shows")
        ordering = ("organization", "slug")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_share_url(self):
        return "http://{0}{1}".format(Site.objects.get_current(), self.get_absolute_url())

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("podcasting_show_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    @property
    def current_episode(self):
        try:
            return self.episode_set.published().order_by("-published")[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None
```

I am able to perform CRUD functionality of the photologue app in the admin - so that fact (in conjunction with the stack trace - where the first exception is being thrown in imagekit app), leads me to believe that the error is solely due to the cache name generation code in imagekit.

However, I have spent more than a few hours trying to pinpoint what is causing the errror -but can't locate it. Is this a known bug with django-imagekit or am I missing something?

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Can you share your podcast model?

Comment: @ChillarAnand I have included the code for Show model - I could not add the others as the text limit was breached. However the code is available on [github](https://github.com/rizumu/django-podcasting)